# Getting date_popup new value with JS

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm currently working on a module with a form where people enter information about their order and select products, where the product selection is handled by JavaScript.

The handling of the form will happen with AJAX.

But my current problem is that when outputting my form with the date_popup type, my JavaScript can't get it's value. This is the form element.

```
$form['date'] = array(
        '#type' => 'date_popup',
        '#title' => t('Datum'),
        '#id' => 'new-order-date',
        '#date_label_position' => '',
        '#default_value' => $today,
        '#date_type' => DATE_DATETIME,
        '#date_timezone' => date_default_timezone(),
        '#date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
        '#date_increment' => 1,
        '#date_year_range' => '0:+3',
        '#datepicker_options' => array('minDate' => 'today'),
    );
```

So, when processing the JS request, the value of the input text box is never changed. This is what I'm using for getting the selected date.

```
var dateField = document.getElementById("new-order-date-datepicker-popup-0");
var selectedDate = dateField.value;
```

However, this always returns the default date, not the date I picked.

My form is generated with this function.

```
function expoline_order_add_form($form, &$form_state) {

    if (func_num_args() > 2) {
        $client = func_get_arg(2);
    } else {
        $client = 0;
    }

    $clientoptions = array();
    $query = db_query("SELECT * FROM {expoline_clients}");
  foreach ($query as $currentclient) {
        $clientoptions[$currentclient->cid] = $currentclient->name;
    };

    $form['client'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Klant'),
        '#default_value' => $client,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#options' => $clientoptions,
        '#multiple' => FALSE,
    );
    $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $form['date'] = array(
        '#type' => 'date_popup',
        '#title' => t('Datum'),
        '#id' => 'new-order-date',
        '#date_label_position' => '',
        //'#default_value' => $today,
        '#date_type' => DATE_DATETIME,
        '#date_timezone' => date_default_timezone(),
        '#date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
        '#date_increment' => 1,
        '#date_year_range' => '0:+3',
        '#datepicker_options' => array('minDate' => 'today'),
    );

    $form['save-order'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('value'),
    );
    $form['#prefix'] = '<div class="my-form-class">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

    return $form;

}
```

And this is my JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      var oTable = $('#datatable-1').dataTable();
      var pTable = $('#datatable-2').dataTable();

      var currentOrder = {};

      var selectDropdown = document.getElementById("edit-client");
      var currentClient = selectDropdown.options[selectDropdown.selectedIndex].value;

      var dateField = document.getElementById("new-order-date-datepicker-popup-0");
      var selectedDate = dateField.value;

      currentOrder.client = currentClient;
      currentOrder.date = selectedDate;
      currentOrder.products = [];

      $('.product-row').dblclick(function() {

        var clickedProduct = {};

        clickedProduct.ID = $(this).children().eq(0).text();

        if (currentOrder.products[clickedProduct.ID]) {
          currentOrder.products[clickedProduct.ID].amount++;
          var elementID = 'product-' + clickedProduct.ID;
          document.getElementById(elementID).value = currentOrder.products[clickedProduct.ID].amount;
        }
        else {
          var newOrderLine = {};
          newOrderLine.productName = $(this).children().eq(2).text();
          newOrderLine.amount = 1;
          currentOrder.products[clickedProduct.ID] = (newOrderLine);
          //currentOrder.products[clickedProduct.ID].productName = $(this).children().eq(2).text()
          //currentOrder.products[clickedProduct.ID].amount = 1;
          oTable.fnAddData( [
            $(this).children().eq(1).text(),
            '<input id="product-' + clickedProduct.ID + '" type="text" value="1" size="3">',]
          );
        }

        console.log(currentOrder);
      });


      $('#products-paint').click(function() {
        pTable.fnFilter('paint');
      });
      $('#products-linemarkings').click(function() {
        //pTable.fnFilter('linemarkeringen');

        var saveData = {};
        saveData.client = currentClient;
        saveData.products = [];
        var product = {};
        product.name = 'Fruitsap';
        product.amount = 1;
        saveData.products.push(product);
        $.post( "http://localhost/expoline/test", currentOrder, function( data ) {
          //$( ".result" ).html( data );
          alert("succes");
        });
      });
```

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you creating the form in your own function? (it looks like you are but just to be sure) Why are you not setting the date field '#default_value' when the form is rebuilt? It would help if we could see the whole form build function and ajax callback function

Comment: What do you mean with 'creating the form in your own function'?

Comment: you say you are "working on a module with a form". is the form array being created in your module? If so it would be helpful to see it.

Comment: Have edited my op with the form function.

Comment: How is the ajax being called on the form? You don't seems to be using the drupal ajax system

Comment: My ajax calls are working fine, I can get all the information that I want. The only problem, which is my original question, is that JS can't get the selected date.

Comment: Which brings me back to why aren't you using the Drupal Form api and it's ajax functionality, doing so would have avoided your problem and save you a lot of work.

Comment: Because the page where the form is put, is a page with the form, and two datatables. One of the datatables is empty, while the other one is filled with products. Doubleclicking a product adds it to the empty datatable (via JS), like in a shopping cart. After you've added all the products, you press a button, JS returns the array of the order [ClientID, Date, Products[]]. The problem is that I can't get the right date in my JS array.

Comment: ok, we will forget about the whole form api and drupal ajax. Can we see the function that completes your ajax request and returns the [ClientID, Date, Products[]] data?

Comment: Edited my op :)

Comment: your '#default_value' is commented out. Also, try it without the datepicker as this has caused me a few problems in the past. Other than that I am not sure and this is where I have to hand this question over to someone else.

Comment: Yeah, I commented it out to see if that would solve it, but now I just get an empty value (again, the 'default') when I try to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I feel slightly embarrassed now, but the solution was actually quite simple.

As you can see from my JS, the 'selectedDate' gets set AS THE PAGE LOADS, not when the button is clicked. So of course, altering the date won't have an effect on the selectedDate variable.

Case closed.